# Motivation$\frac{\sqrt[3]{ab}+\sqrt[3]{ac}}{2\left(\sqrt[3]{ab}+\sqrt[3]{bc}+\sqrt[3]{ac}\right)}.\left(\sqrt[3]{abc}+5\right) +4a\ge 2\sqrt{4a^2+5a}$

Tags: inequality

> Prove $$\frac{\sqrt[3]{ab}+\sqrt[3]{ac}}{2\left(\sqrt[3]{ab}+\sqrt[3]{bc}+\sqrt[3]{ac}\right)}\cdot\left(\sqrt[3]{abc}+5\right) +4a\ge 2\sqrt{4a^2+5a}, \tag{*}$$when $a,b,c>0.$

In the comment section of [this topic,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4814036/finding-small-min-limits-abc-2-sqrta-2bc3-sqrtb-2ca3-sqrtc-2ab3) River Li write about an isolated fudging as an shortly quick way for a non-homogenous inequality $$4(a+b+c)+\sqrt[3]{abc}+5\ge 2\left(\sqrt{4a^2+5a}+\sqrt{4b^2+5b}+\sqrt{4c^2+5c}\right). $$

I was quite curious about how the solver come up with $(*).$

Also, I tried to prove $(*)$ by squaring but it's very complicated.

Hope you share some thoughts for this isolated fudging. Thanks for interest.

*Relevant information.*

There're some non-homogenous inequality posted in Mathematics Stack Exchange. I leave it here.

[Problem 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4723013/a-b-c0-prove-that-frac1-sqrt3abc5-ge-2-sqrt3-left-frac1-sqr?rq=1), [Problem 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4817081/prove-3a4bc-sqrt3abc-ge-2-left-sqrtb-left4b5a-right-sqrtc-l/4817294#4817294), [Problem 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4747800/prove-frac1-sqrt3xy3-ge-2-sqrt3-left-frac1-sqrtx2-frac1/4748020#4748020), [Problem 4.](https://rt3abc20-ge-2-sum-cyc-sqrta4aabbcca-if)

Comment: Yes, I want to know the proof as well. I did not deal with it before.

Comment: @RiverLi I found a proof. It is even more general.

Comment: Congratulation.

Comment: @RiverLi I post it. Hope there's no mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Proof.**

We'll prove the following general result for $a,b,c>0,$ the constant $0\le k\le 5$ and an arbitrary negative expression $T$ represent to $a,b,c.$

> $$\color{black}{\frac{\sqrt[3]{ab}+\sqrt[3]{ac}}{2\left(\sqrt[3]{ab}+\sqrt[3]{bc}+\sqrt[3]{ac}\right)}\cdot\left((k+1)\sqrt[3]{abc}+(5-k)T\right) +4a\ge 2\sqrt{a\left(4a+k\sqrt[3]{abc}+(5-k)T\right) }.} \tag{*}$$

For easily verifying, we prove
$$\color{black}{\frac{ab+ac}{2\left(ab+bc+ca\right)}\cdot\left((k+1)abc+(5-k)T\right) +4a^3\ge 2\sqrt{a^3\left(4a^3+kabc+(5-k)T\right) }.}$$
or
$$\color{black}{\frac{b+c}{2\left(ab+bc+ca\right)}\cdot\left[(k+1)bc+\dfrac{(5-k)T}{a}\right] +4a\ge 2\sqrt{4a^2+kbc+\dfrac{(5-k)T}{a} }.} \tag{1}$$

Notice that by AM-GM $$\frac{b+c}{2\left(ab+bc+ca\right)}=\frac{1}{2a+\dfrac{2bc}{b+c}}\ge \frac{1}{2a+\sqrt{bc}}.$$Thus, it's enough to prove the stronger inequality of $(1)$ $$\frac{(k+1)bc+\dfrac{(5-k)T}{a}}{2a+\sqrt{bc}}+4a\ge 2\sqrt{4a^2+kbc+\dfrac{(5-k)T}{a} },$$which is true by AM-GM.

Indeed,
\begin{align*}
    \frac{(k+1)bc+\dfrac{(5-k)T}{a}}{2a+\sqrt{bc}}+4a&=\frac{(k+1)bc+\dfrac{(5-k)T}{a}}{2a+\sqrt{bc}}+2a-\sqrt{bc}+2a+\sqrt{bc}\\&=
\frac{4a^2+kbc+\dfrac{(5-k)T}{a}}{2a+\sqrt{bc}}+2a+\sqrt{bc}\\&\ge 2\sqrt{4a^2+kbc+\dfrac{(5-k)T}{a} }.
\end{align*}

Hence, $(1)$ is proven and $(*)$ is subsequently true.

When $k=0; T=1$ we obtain $$\color{black}{\frac{\sqrt[3]{ab}+\sqrt[3]{ac}}{2\left(\sqrt[3]{ab}+\sqrt[3]{bc}+\sqrt[3]{ac}\right)}\cdot\left(\sqrt[3]{abc}+5\right) +4a\ge 2\sqrt{a\left(4a+5\right) }.}$$